# Having trouble with variable multiplied with a logarithm.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have tried solving the following equation.

$$f(N)=(N^{1/3})*(log_{2} N)^{2/3}$$

I guess I need to clarify my question.
I need to solve for N somehow.
For instance, if f(N) = 256, then what would N have to be.

I'm stumped.  I've researched logrithm properties and exponential properties and I have no idea where to even start.   Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: What equation are you having trouble with? There aren't any equations in your post, only expressions - hence, there's nothing to solve.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Unless we know what this equates to, we can't answer the question. Is it $N * (\log_2N) = 1$ for example?

Comment: Well, for starters, the first expression is not equivalent to the second and third.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my question.  Let me know if it's not good enough.

Comment: There is no way to solve it at the level of algebra-precalculus, other than trial and error. There are more advanced methods, such as Newton's Method, that produce arbitrarily good approximations to the answer. But for $2048$, try letting $N$ be a power of 2.

Comment: So basically, what your telling me is to use my graphing calculator to solve for N?

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Some calculators also have a "solve" button, which lets you program in an equation and then solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Formally, this is done using the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).
$$\begin{align} N^{1/3}\cdot \log^{2/3}_2 N &=  X
\\ \sqrt N \cdot 2\log_2 \sqrt N &= X^{3/2}
\\ e^{\ln \sqrt N} \cdot \ln \sqrt N &= \frac 1 2 X^{3/2} \ln 2
\\ \ln \sqrt N &= W(\frac 1 2 X^{3/2} \ln 2)
\\ N &= e ^ {2 W(\frac 1 2 X^{3/2} \ln 2)} \end{align}$$
However if, given some $X$, you want to find the numeric value of $N$, it won't help you much - in general, an approximation is the best you can expect.

For simple cases, you should be able to find $N$ that looks like $2^n$ or $2^{2^n}$, satisfying your equation.

Comment: I look at the statement of the question, and I look at your answer, and I wonder how you decided that the question you are answering is the one OP intended to ask.

Comment: I figured it wouldn't hurt to know. I've made it better now, I hope.